# How to render bezier curve with array?

Tags: rendering, bezier-curves

I'm trying to render this circle of balls up to this plate, I'm using for this a bezier curve with an array modifier but every time I try to render, the balls don't appear.

[image: picture]

Comment: I tried in 2.80 and 2.79. Not sure how you made a ball with your curve initially, but I added a curve with geometry and bevel and it does appear at render. And I used your modifiers stack too.

Comment: Is it a setting on the _other_ object.. (the disc) ? eg a hidden surface set to render, or a different level of render-subd causing your array to be concealed? Maybe share your file via [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: @Kiskit I followed this two tutorials:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgdobdXzKM4
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkCq7StwXb8

Comment: I agree with Robin, please share the file

Comment: Hi guys (@RobinBetts @Kiskit), sorry for this later answer. Unfortunately, I lost this file, but I started fresh and retried and it worked. I think it was something to do with the mesh of the balls I modeled because I followed the tutorial again and the only thing different was this balls that I had to remodel. Anyhow thanks for the help.